# Changed ssh port to 1234, can't connect to server, fail2ban in use

Tags: ssh, fail2ban, port

I just changed my ssh port to 1234 and now i cant access my server any more.
Also I set `AllowUsers stephan` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

I have fail2ban installed and i am trying to login as root user. password is correct.

when i try to login via root it gives me permission denied:

```
ssh root@192.168.2.126 -p 1234
```

The succeeding tries it just halts at some point and does nothing.

The same happens when I try

```
ssh stephan@192.168.2.126 -p 1234
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

fail2ban banned my ip for some minutes, afterwards I was able to login with the user stephan.

1. I changed the user to root by typing: `su - root`
2. Then I was able to edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to say `AllowUsers stephan root`
3. reloading the ssh service: `sudo service ssh reload`

login with root and stephan now works.